# Generating JSON with Jinja2

Tags: python, python-2.x, google-app-engine

I needed quickly to represent a list in json format. I wrote the following front-end in jinja2 with google appengine.

```
{
"title": "The Basics - Networking",
"description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
"movies": [

{% if results %}
    {% for scored_document in results %}

        { "title": "{{ scored_document.fields.0.value|safe | replace('"','') }}", "releaseYear": "2014",
 {% set testing = scored_document.fields.8.value|displayimg %}
                                    {% if testing and testing != 'False' %}
        "img": "{{ testing }}",
   {% endif %}
        "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/{{ scored_document.fields.8.value|int|safe }}.html"}{% if not loop.last %}
        ,
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}{% endif %}
]
}
```

There are several unclean errors with wrong variable names because I copied the code from an example but the [output](http://koolbusiness.com/in.json) is good:

```
{ "title": "The Basics - Networking", "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!", "movies": [ { "title": "1200 SQFT SITES available for sale Nelamangala for sale--7lacs-30*40 sqft ", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wEuEmcPNEXfA37EATiWaQ0odK09nAjcaiL5HR_WBCr5RTyU6LeKkfSHH9kQkcchfRToRE4z7UKsfrOtlZnwTxmMI2Xc=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6371047123189760.html"} , { "title": "Buy prestige glass top 3 burner gas stove from nbhomeshop", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_rL9pl62uSq4g9csH1aBK1cniie_JUEAZwUIKQAxlhjIH875O1D4aVVgV6blxGECgsOvSRcL15pdk3-JAmEI_zltcw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6469401068961792.html"} , { "title": "angular js online training,software courses,android course,seo course,Corporate training institutes in Hyderabad.", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mcih7gjnhgF-R6--Kj45X16U7j2GjpQhI5_JaU3XOS_cIBIrQbhHb14rseIlyqSUZALDj3g-ofXKhm_JgvMnP0ns8Q=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6735288535613440.html"} , { "title": "angular js online training,software courses,android course,seo course,Corporate training institutes in Hyderabad.", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Gpv6aHVU3rIRGv5vvT2SCkPJYB5gtEdhKnn3yBf_Gurmz87uUlN_kEGISoGCFriDm21ZFRFCSqGPH2fsuXACjTbipCk=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5561960915533824.html"} , { "title": "Improve Memory and Brain Power with Branole X", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TX3EGNSULaNOJWsxgvOXP6JHne24nnYFgWEcrHrNLKgb5OKFaH6WoI6853CQDyOgRYDFMF9VCSmLAp1rfE2T4gjduw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6742589980016640.html"} , { "title": "Aqua Grand +water purifier For Best Price in Megashope", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mXzD6eG-xMr_cGN9GCinVjBCw_MdwfoY0clQ9vS-MEjJWumg4IhdZRSxhxTh17r1MJTalwRikyAX3HOCz_5DUyolFQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5527058937544704.html"} , { "title": "Dell Honored at 2016 International Design Excellence Awards", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ftXusdPY_UZlDxRFv3xq-sc_DPDO9pCG5GwhJGeAsC9fUqTi2Grz9RNlWwY4xel5NHoOcAOURLNOQBuCe-gJCvgO=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5592851125633024.html"} , { "title": "Dell Honored at 2016 International Design Excellence Awards", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/D5kF6KJ0YXMB-kFYropQdRbNusngKg1DjEvKheo_aPrd1wn1vqRjvRfMC2Up0S8KHDlIsFoSKBuvC8VHj5ktUEqCrZA=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5035817758097408.html"} , { "title": "Dell Honored at 2016 International Design Excellence Awards", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TV2YoFBoQA3ATreDpqibPf_rps7H__MA-ctgZHtOJoIUMjo6sh8IIDmkaSkakjWIwhoR4EpIj-say4JXmXsVgMs-2vs=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5556571268448256.html"} , { "title": "Buy gold necklace online at Amethystbyrahulpopli", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kabOt5lt7EoRVxU-YkAvw8J4uLpoOfjFOXplJjQUYmxR_Jj4liL59fSQub3qNNFxXl-A4P45PglKHWcFrC0V3zh2lQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6155801079054336.html"} , { "title": "Buy MLM software & Build MLM business online ", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/464yjWWhP16YDMJzzn_JN3GCW0KEO1xaOMAtLDEUzAhfX_xPNxu5qZIWPg8vQ81LpVluLzfNPANKLXYLCQxCG_Hhug=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5363524836524032.html"} , { "title": "Dell Honored at 2016 International Design Excellence Awards", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4nQU7IEgS4-5D_MDkxOzKR_76acQYY1PhWIEaJpCzbc3BgD7V7f1AVDeT6w5suXQOvmfbXobcqV7IMNSU9WfxHiy9rw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5518504436432896.html"} , { "title": "Famous Vastu Consultant Services in Gurgaon", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6151819375935488.html"} , { "title": "Fully furnished Boys PG in sohna road gurgaon", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6430480075325440.html"} , { "title": "Dell Honored at 2016 International Design Excellence Awards", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Hl7GSSCQQJA_KY-33FB6uqVvOqgNPj8AKdXAj0jsJaFSlo2_6KPvJfMY2NKUUu6MkmhIeZm384EwOBT3Y4Y6qfGqz0w=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5616690073174016.html"} , { "title": "Renting Leasing Residential Property in Sohna Road Gurgaon", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6124910868955136.html"} , { "title": "Shivagiri Township Phase I., International SchoolSingle plot - (60 x 40) Rs.2400 Sq Ft", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5Yf1wdA8FwjUQJCxFUarVxVqQEBVw1X-rfzOccwiWsxHDFdFSs4NgBhYBOnDEjKwlR7boQS6Qe1U6DC4cXCSYD7l6g=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6351520859684864.html"} , { "title": "Buy Fully Furnished Commercial Property in Gurgaon", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5025919469092864.html"} , { "title": "Dell Honored at 2016 International Design Excellence Awards", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/t1KEzWjVqxYFQAiLkxmOl1xveiyUeQ8MhrAuH_KYodsUwtidNha7T0LyzdzIkD70FKo2mGHyHuPwWd35BYbGpIv_Pso=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/4912444554084352.html"} , { "title": "Aqua Grand +water purifier For Best Price in Megashope", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/H9QBDOXFyN6jvLF-7qg9Mm6bfvgHccfWt6VGs53oq-6Lynh-7EFAycGC9ysanmqZww4OPfNo3gFhfjjgT6WcH_YexKA=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6186115495100416.html"} , { "title": "ANSYS COURSES IN CHENNAI | BEST ANSYS TRAINING - 9884433249", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5609388628770816.html"} , { "title": "AutoCAD Courses for Civil Engineers in Chennai | Civil AutoCAD Training", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6120900711677952.html"} , { "title": "AutoCAD Training Institute in Chennai | Best AutoCAD Institute", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6319819437637632.html"} , { "title": "Aqua Grand +water purifier For Best Price in Megashope", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dBEZi48stLzoSa935dSwrG6XG9rHWauVibD6hL-qNMyPSyl9NQ3r-RDL31__Y1z5x0J9ypv2406WA5EWlQN15_yQcw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5028809445212160.html"} , { "title": "SEBS PROVIDING HOME BASED WORKS ..", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oz6lXftn2ZAo72l94ZIZDt8k5zma8Qi_Sj590HD0arbqlZYw5Q9TbHGeDMaOw4DPC4wXj3sgV354Uq_q1ceOFiI9Ag=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5042552803688448.html"} , { "title": "India's most successful online examination software - Tutoreal", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OU9YwSGw0ipdKrmhbrvj4zgQf1zB_q4vHQExrkq3Qhlz1Em29QkpFLEIQGuRtW5R34eU06vfEMXMBMzlgIb3LmpgYw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6090008890966016.html"} , { "title": "DO THE PART TIME EARN REGULARLY", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eOPNfb9X0Bww0hWgmkDRWCMDVF1UbD6FxC7dUa7vObSakSe-0ry6_1gzfBqlhqohbePu-G3YQCuNEjcG9O2oiJA_=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6449927687241728.html"} , { "title": "WHO WANT EXTRA INCOME DO PART TIME JOB", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rAk2Tigz2eq9ObmQial0dGqhunIDmoOslLo-mWjtoY_XCX8Zdt3WLGLDH4N73dTstCiuGKGRhPzmTYtFOeuP2jXkyn4=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5756869484216320.html"} , { "title": "FEELING BOAR THEN FILLUP THE FORMS", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/qg58D3wCeFW6dGqlbIwocJ21HT3-1jv1Yu8mKBPLLAgNo0w9Zuo1ddRvbVnXkCrHG5takW6Qu90JG44axHByiF05=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6081454389854208.html"} , { "title": "ONCE REGISTER IN SEBS TAKE ONE YEAR INCOME", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LFUJB7ftdt01IcURnDPp1sp11luU_I16lETvCZJy86ndhEPw3t8YUBuf8Mwylktj3RucJX62vlTrMJZME23cOfQMJg=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5029901172211712.html"} , { "title": "Pay Per Click (PPC) Services Company Delhi & Across India", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nkfVvC8BWZaOCQKKQxhWngEXX1zUTQVhgfWLQnGoFIn3JD7xg5CmdrZ0JFmC8PxUm10l-hZ1dBRGYwvMjfcO_QllRQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5046438675349504.html"} , { "title": "SEBS PROVIDING WORKS FOR STUDENTS", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pS_UVwB-a_GUMBqEHOlyX4oubrbCrDOBz41KW_DWkMGSyFcbjAtVr9hbO_rg4YhE-XN5wTAVF7yCLBgLWL5J-vJWS2o=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6334093358792704.html"} , { "title": "PART TIME HOME BASED WORKS ARE AVAILABLE ", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DxEGyB6jwYQNIC95qcTa1Ty_mR8UOt6ac9hI3SiSxALUe-2pxsZpZMyu2E4SQKYQrDREP1T-tPGie3C2-fmwKqSM5Gw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6360722558681088.html"} , { "title": "JUST FILLUP THE FORMS WE WILL PROVIDE MONEY", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4afOgWiVS9Mp1CqaBWRKOJciIeKtlx6BcZtje6olRNTeTrIXGLYsa0_UURL9MNjurD1txcJJFmKaWmQVQRB4G7kl3q8=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5335997048946688.html"} , { "title": "NOW U GET WEEKLY PAYMENT THROUGH LAPTAP", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/l8lSMOQAlwFjaFfGJYlHHxZauN3FNyKoKWCR_15JEqtZFdU0Fl-acBmNovThWdxaCvByeNxYTdEMs6RSsVlYqUNTQwU=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5271450132938752.html"} , { "title": "HURRY UP VACANCIES ARE START", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rE5RiFhsinGtWeBEnXhB-txkj5A5SBPzaQ1gOdjozreykKxo4D367WXvYItUV5tfzuq3IoregaRLahk3OO0OJqXw6rU=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5208193451950080.html"} , { "title": "web designing company in visakhapatnam ", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7HmV0NElSz8vHAtJmN-FUJF0PqzYtey-Yu9KzAxOWExsNsmZYmYaohfl8UbsRrBj0VfP8ga0VfX9vBqycPTiVtMG9sw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/4964108984123392.html"} , { "title": "CALORIZED OXYGEN LANCING PIPES", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AZTmI7wTK9i7IdeGLNefH312nJPjgSeMg7YLXg9ikmXc1_IpmJyJWf6vR0BKhYplYXwHqY9Y0TmZj9tOOmlzl8XWjw=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5063230118428672.html"} , { "title": "Best restaurants in Delhi , Satya Niketan", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FwCr3e3EaikXod8Wp6PELnISvU92_ArD79YqRt_q3yb8YjZmwXtqS5B884sCMJaPKi_ma3m7uNuVbbrAUxVgNXbaYg=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5225620952842240.html"} , { "title": "Artificial Lawn Grass Manufacturer and Supplier in delhi- Dspaze", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hDtSO48SIFa_IEojY7V1rc8f3JHjh7iH6GmrLhRH2SNfX6vgrYUk8IMFuuoJDTajyIcxGBoxccprIvZojuEkqULX_g=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6114783336071168.html"} , { "title": "Big data training in bangalore", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vaV5q_cW9G6V850gtf4j9OMxMFBn2wXi4b-h4O0sJib_-fNpChVi2rnN2qJAEsMkXKsNOhpW-Fty0hchLptr9wSNR48=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5313711805825024.html"} , { "title": "Contact Verdure - Best Swimming Pool Vendor in Delhi ", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JCbNplL03XfL-r7DAiNdmN9YUM0KbhpCxtxijieq2xe57C2lAznwCZWozD6277nFM1yuUkVjKa-cPeXpGfp5OhvebQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6364646816612352.html"} , { "title": "Aqua Grand +water purifier For Best Price in Megashope", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Qw_cEOu8ECK4RBXlRhCCc_Pa0ks0tI8EOp-8xFsCpKx4RJYY1_7XXDc3HqV1c2PfN_hHrie8AjbkwqNzMsreA_PRtA=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5876661759246336.html"} , { "title": "Scanner Tenders, Tenders By Scanner, Tenders For Scanner", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5238746909769728.html"} , { "title": "Dr. Arun Kumar Singh - Best Endocrinologist in Faridabad, NCR", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8mdHMf2xTufAPasbX6ButMBRTBQf4WvnU6bUAquxLcKfLoHykrQ88LH5niPoIPqdKiicZXnELCS90nVZDa_jxeCX=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5286396216475648.html"} , { "title": "Wholesale Women Clothing Suppliers", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lD5xaOsaBAT4xchvXzQNHm81wnNdTG-M-w8iq2djhRRp4CZH8NyOxjz9XWlxUwB2N7zf7onYLVlsN0f9eSUD7ZT85A=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5857946976124928.html"} , { "title": "Earn Money Online RS 24000/Month F/P/T", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AdK3MLruGvx66rRO7567EZivvSOI8I-6RDrS_Bo59Az6-PhRHzu1YW6ECYDzdcsT374W-xCEPIy2gJx-xuSV1LtTAQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5053740119752704.html"} , { "title": "Job problem solution in Mumbai", "releaseYear": "2014", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/4977441099481088.html"} , { "title": "Best HR Policy Classes in Delhi NCR", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ONkJrdtozkk6E1_0ZFjNubFCJUhr2tGEd0HaC1U8ZwCdVemPOQfeDWPPih6QJogRwPQo3PfVMHvFg9G6wnNJgQeXpQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/5224881413160960.html"} , { "title": "A Dedicated Web Portal/Website Of Solan District.", "releaseYear": "2014", "img": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lLSF35XwnQ7ld4cBuTSs3lZdeMSG8PyKGb6qTHFcqBlGH0NxOxI9K8MqjT9vZ3vYeT0Lr9N3akcEWfvVaGFpzl9quQ=s150", "url": "https://www.koolbusiness.com/newvi/6343054942273536.html"} ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the `.json` output being served from a template file, make use of [the `json` module](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/json.html) function of `webapp2_extras`.

The current response headers for the `/in.json` page has:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

whereas, it should be ideally: **`application/json`**.

---

Why you should avoid creating a json in text is because if you later want to add/remove a key, or iterate over a creating a certain key, you might run into syntax issues. Debugging those syntax errors would be a pain since you run 3 level deep in the existing code already.

Instead, create a python `dict` in the handler code itself, and send a response as follows:

```
from webapp2_extras import json
...
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
self.response.write(json.encode(your_python_dict))
```

This way, a client will not receive a malformed JSON response ever, and the server would simply issue a **5xx** error code.

Comment: It works your way. It was even easier.